# Obj-C: Pass method arguments to nested block

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to consume some JSON data. I have to do this in a number of my view controllers. I'm trying to refactor my code and remove some duplication. I would like to know how I could pass, for instance, a `NSArray` object to the completion block of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`?

I have attempted the following to no avail.

```
-(void)request:(NSArray *)jsonArray
{
    // ...

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         jsonArray = responseObject;

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                        }
                        );
     }
                                     failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
     }
     ];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: Pass a callback block into your method. Use the block to send back your array.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You say you want to pass an array _in_, but you're setting the array to something different inside the completion Block. Please clarify.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The service returns a JSON array in `responseObject`

Comment: But what are you trying to do with it? Why are you setting the `jsonArray` pointer, which was an argument, to the object you get as the response?

Comment: @JoshCaswell The `jsonArray` argument would be the source array of the UITableViewController's tableview. I would just like a method I could reuse in multiple table view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `jsonArray` to be an `out` method parameter so you can set its value within your method. With an asynchronous request like you have here this is heavily discouraged, but nonetheless.

Your method definition would change to:

```
-(void)request:(out NSArray **)jsonArray;
```

Calls to this method would change to:

```
[object request:&anArray];
```

And your completion handler would set the array with:

```
*jsonArray = responseObject;
```

For what it's worth, I agree with CrimsonChris who suggested using a callback block to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case I understand you, I can advice you to do like this:

```
-(void)request:(NSArray *)jsonArray 
   compltition:(void(^)(NSDIctionary *response))complition {
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     jsonArray = responseObject;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    ^{
                        //returning response 
                         complition(response);
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    }
                    );
 }
                                 failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
 }
 ];

[operation start];
}
```

and where you are calling this function:

```
[self request:jsonArray complition:^(NSDictionary *response) {
NSLog(@"Response = %@, response")
//and you can parse and reload your table
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining the function in a helper class, making `jsonArray` an instance variable of that class, instead of a function argument.

Comment: it is not a good approach. when you decide to to somwthing multythreading or move this function to another class from view controller this will be a problem

Comment: @Roma Sorry, I wasn't clear. I created a helper class and defined the function there, and declared `jsonArray` as an NSMutableArray instance variable. It does the job and I have no problems when using the function in multiple view controllers. What you and others suggested of passing a block does not work. It still gives the `Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)` error message

Comment: this error mean you should declare variable like this __block NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new];

Comment: For anyone who's interested, passing in a callback block into the method is the correct approach - as suggested by CrimsonChris in the comments to the question